# Using Logging with Multiprocessing Module

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I need to create a single logger that can be used throughout my python package, but some of the functions implement multiprocessing.  I want all those functions to write to the same log file just like everything else.

I know at Python 3.2+ there is a built in way to do this, but I need to back port to Python 2.7.x as well.

Is there any code out there that works well with both multiprocessing and non-multiprocessing functions for logging?

Normally, I would create a log as such:

```
module = sys.modules['__main__'].__file__
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG,
                format='%(name)s (%(levelname)s): %(message)s')
log = logging.getLogger(module)
fh = RotatingFileHandler(arguments.o, mode='a', maxBytes=2*1024*1024,
                        backupCount=2, encoding=None, delay=0)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %    (message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.addHandler(fh)
```

Then the output would write to a single file.  It works great, but when I implement this, this code will create multiple files, which I do not want.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Are you putting this code inside the usual `if __name__ == '__main__':` conditional? Remember that **everything** that isn't an import or function/class definition should go there when using `multiprocessing`.

Comment: @Bakuriu - I'm doing the log creation at the module level because this is for a python package.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality to do this in Python >= 3.2 (via the `QueueHandler` and `QueueListener` classes, as described [here](http://plumberjack.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/using-logging-with-multiprocessing.html)) is available for Python 2.7 through the [`logutils`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logutils) project.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Can this be used to write messages out to a single log file?

Comment: So when I try to pass the log file to multiprocessor, it throws a pickle error, can you provide a simple example of how to use this tool?

Comment: @josh1234 The post I linked to has a working example.

Comment: The example does utilize your package rather some custom code.  I can substitute the QueueHandler class with the one in the package.  How do you use the QueueListener with multiprocessing?

Comment: @josh1234 see the Python logging cookbook for more information: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html